# ¿Cómo listar los archivos de una ruta y permitir borrarlos desde la web?

Tags: php, php5

Tengo este código para listar los archivos de un directorio, pero necesito que a la vez me dé la opción de eliminar archivos, según el usuario desee.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

```
$path= "mi/ruta";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("No se pudo abrir");
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file!= ".."){
        $enlace= $path.'/'.$file; 
        echo '<a href="$enlace">'.$file.'</a><br>';
    }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
```

Comment: creo que [ESTO](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unlink.php) te puede servir.

Comment: mira esto : https://www.the-art-of-web.com/dirlist-png-table.phps